# Why is the address different when object is returned by value in c++

Tags: c++

```
class A {
  public:
    A(){}
};

A test() {
  A obj1;
  cout<<&obj1<<endl;
  return obj1;
}

int main()
{
  A obj2 = test();
  cout<<&obj2<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

compiled using g++ -std=c++20

The address of obj1 = 0x7ff7bb6b72e8 and obj2 = 0x7ff7bb6b7348,

I was learning what is copy ellision and tested the above code. why is the address different? I thought copy ellision would take place. If I return a vector instead, the address remains same

I created copy and move constructors and assignments as well, and added cout statements, nothing was getting printed during the return value as well, which led me to believe that if no copy or move is happening, copy ellision must be happenining

Comment: "_I thought copy ellision would take place._": No, there is no guaranteed copy elision from `obj1` to `obj2` in your example. Why do you expect one?

Comment: When you return an object by value it's a different object. Try returning the object by ref and you should get the same address.

Comment: "_which led me to believe that if no copy or move is happening_": Please show how you did that. Either you did it wrong or the compiler made a different decision regarding the copy elision, e.g. because you changed the body of `test`.

Comment: its giving me different results each time, now I am getting same address but no couts, notice this https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3zgpt43qa where i added copy and move assignments and constructors, but none of the couts are printed, may be in this case copy ellision is happening now??

Comment: @ShivanshuArora Named return value optimization is non-mandatory copy elision. It is to be expected that the compiler makes different choices depending on the exact circumstances.

Comment: ok, thanks for this, my assumption wrong then

Answer (score 4):

Copy elision does not guarantee that the addresses of `obj1` and `obj2` will be the same. It only guarantees that the construction of the object will be elided. The function `test()` will construct `obj1` in its own scope, and that object will be used to directly initialize `obj2` in `main()` without invoking any copy/move constructors. But the actual addresses can differ.

To better understand this, let's look at the generated assembly (full output is available here - [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MGc1or5af)):

```
test():
    sub     rsp, 16
    lea     rax, [rbp-1]       // Address of obj1
    call    A::A()             // Constructor call for obj1
    mov     rsi, rax           // Printing the address of obj1
    call    std::basic_ostream::operator<<
    leave
    ret

main:
    sub     rsp, 16
    call    test()
    lea     rax, [rbp-1]       // Address of obj2
    mov     rsi, rax           // Printing the address of obj2
    call    std::basic_ostream::operator<<
    leave
    ret
```

**Stack Address Allocation**

Looking at the assembly, both functions `test()` and `main()` subtract `rsp` (the stack pointer) by 16 bytes when they start. This is typically to allocate space on the stack for local variables and other data. In this case, that data includes our objects `obj1` and `obj2` respectively.

**Object Construction**

In the `test()` function, the constructor for `A` is called for `obj1`. Its memory location corresponds to `[rbp-1]`, which is the stack address for `obj1`. Similarly, in main, even though the constructor isn't explicitly called for `obj2` due to copy elision, the memory for `obj2` is designated at `[rbp-1]`.

**Address Output**

The program outputs the addresses `0x7ffd25c73fef` and `0x7ffd25c7400f` for `obj1` and `obj2`, respectively. We can see that these addresses differ, which is consistent with the observation from the assembly output. **Each function has its own stack frame**, so even though the relative offset from `rbp` (`[rbp-1]`) is the same for both `obj1` and `obj2`, their absolute addresses in memory are different.

Moreover, looking at the difference between the two addresses (`0x20` in hexadecimal), it's evident that the discrepancy isn't just about the two objects: other factors like function call mechanics, return addresses, and possibly other data are also influencing the stack's layout.

Comment: If copy elision is done the addresses _must_ be the same. The point of copy elision is not that a constructor call is skipped, but that two normally distinct objects are merged into one object. What you are showing here is that copy elision is _not_ done and in that case the copy/move constructor _must_ be called. That the compiler was able to inline the trivial copy/move constructor call which doesn't actually perform any action in OP's example doesn't change that. You can't look at compiler output to make that determination.

Comment: At best what the emitted code is showing is that named return value optimization which is non-mandatory _is_ done here, but that the exception of https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#3 for types with trivial copy/move/destruction is applied instead which permits (but doesn't require) to do the inverse of copy elision: Introducing an additional new object for the return value. This is made mandatory by the Itanium C++ ABI used by the compilation in your example. Add a non-trivial destructor and that's not going to happen anymore.